# Why did C++ introduce new functions for IO when they already exist in C?

Tags: c++, io

IO involves reading and writing bytes from or to a memory location. That is all there is to as far as I know. Thus, when functions like printf, scanf, putch, getch and File IO functions already existed in C in stdio.h, why then was new mechanism and concept of stream introduced in C++ for IO?

Does C not the concept of stream when we look at stdin and stdout?

Also, I keep coming across the term "standard" IO. Is there something such as nonstandard IO too?

Comment: Because variable argument functions are as non type safe as it can get. The iostream library will call the correct conversion code based on the static type of your variables, without any need for you to specify it in some obscure DSL. Plus, you can define your own `operator<<` for streams, there is no way to extend the `stdio` family of functions with custom format specifiers.

Comment: The C++ IO facilities are arguably easier to use, less error-prone, and can be used with user-defined data types.

Comment: You might as well ask why C++ introduced the `std::string` class, C already have null-terminated strings and functions for handling them. Or why use `std::vector` when one can just use pointers and `malloc`? And so on.

Comment: are you talking about those symbols like %u, %x e.t.c? I know that C++ uses OOP to encapsulate the code that does IO but I am not sure if there is any fundamental difference between C++ IO functions and C IO functions such that we may want to use the C standard IO functions when writing C++ code

Comment: @ Some programmer dude, yes I could ask that question. I am an electronic engineer you see so am wondering about these things. Buy mt question here is about IO only.

Comment: It doesn't use OOP alone. It uses generic programming via templates. A powerful tool in its own right, even more so when coupled with OOD.

Comment: Regarding the formats, thing about what happens if you use e.g. `printf("%s", something_which_is_not_a_pointer_to_char)`. That's valid in C, but C++ adds *strong* type-checking so it's not possible in C++ (unless using the old unsafe C functions).

Comment: Python and other languages also use their own IO meachanisms, although one could call those from the C standard library. Why should that be different on C++? It is also a distinct language.

Comment: It's also worth noting C++ didn't initially introduce anything. It originally relied on the C standard library. The current incarnation of the `std` namespace evolved out of various libraries that existed "in the wild".

Comment: Why do they keep making new models of car each year? We already have cars, right?

Comment: @StoryTeller: ISO C++ has had the standard library since the beginning. When we say "C++" now that's what we mean.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - If you define the beginning at standardization, sure. But C++ did exist in some way shape or form prior to that, since Bjarne's days at Bell Labs. I see great value in learning about how the standardized beast was formed as I do in learning the standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller: When we say "C++" now that's what we mean.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - And the "we" that is "you" is welcome to that opinion. It does not change the history and evolution of the language. If an initiate asks "how" we refer to what is the ISO C++ standard, if they ask "why" then we delve into the days prior to standardization for comparative analysis. When the C++ Primer was the de-facto standard and people were just figuring out how to best use the language; When use-cases in "the wild" eventually dictated the appearance of the standard library, and the formalization of the final specification.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - But perhaps my original wording could have been better. It should have been *"It's also worth noting that prior to standardization, C++ didn't introduce anything"*

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yeah could be so. Although there's a point in the process of anything that's designed, when it is not complete yet. So doesn't really seem worth mentioning :) There was a time when C didn't have I/O, for example, which is before the moment that I/O was added to the project that would become C. I'm not really sure what we're trying to say with such statements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - We're trying to answer a bunch of "why" questions. And immediately learn why they are off-topic on SO :)

Answer (score 4):

> Thus, when functions like printf, scanf, putch, getch and File IO functions already existed in C in stdio.h, why then was new mechanism and concept of stream introduced in C++ for IO?

There are several reasons (and you'll need to read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book). But the `std::ostream` and similar classes enable you to define your own

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const MyClass& obj);
```

and then code (assuming you have some `MyClass obj;` instance)

```
 std::cout << "two is " << 2 << " and obj is " << obj << std::endl;
```

and that is really nice. Standard `printf` does not have that. GNU libc provides as an extension [`printf`  customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html), which nobody uses. And `printf` can be error prone and with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), e.g.

```
// WRONG CODE: scary undefined behavior
const char* fmt = (rand()%2==0)?"this %s":"that %s";
printf(fmt, 34);
```

<sup>(and you should not hope such errors to be statically detected; in practice you'll get a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) at runtime)</sup>

But C++ streams are slightly safer (even if you probably can wreak havoc with them also).
And you can subclass `std::ostream`  too (see also [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)) or have your own [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

> Also, I keep coming across the term "standard" IO. Is there something such as nonstandard IO too?

Yes, low level system calls like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) are only standardized by POSIX (not by [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) specified in [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) which you should read; also, Windows have different ways of reading), and some of them (like [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) ...) are specific to Linux.

You may want to read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: OK, I am aware of using operator overloading for this purpose.

Comment: if you know of a book that will reveal the reasoning behind move to cout, cin from printf, scanf; let me know

Comment: @quantum231 - Try C++ Gems by Stanley B. Lippman

Answer (score 2):

You can derive from the stream class and overload the << and >> operators to achieve your own compatible stream behaviour, for example to a solid state memory device you have to write driver code for.

That said, whilst streams should be objects of a number of types (files, string streams, memory streams, connections to other programs) the old C++ standard library did not do a good job, and many people continued to use printf() because it was so much easier to control the formatting.

Nowadays, compiling overloaded << and >> operators often contributes a significant fraction of a C++ compiler's time  and, even on fast machines, medium-sized projects can take longer than is comfortable to build. So I wouldn't say the problems have been eliminated. There's still a compelling
case for using the old C streams and ignoring the std:: offering, however it's a matter of opinion, Herb Sutter presumably wouldn't agree.

Comment: Actually, to define a new kind of stream you do **not** derive from `std::istream` or `std::ostream` and define the new behavior via overload `operator<<()` or `operator>>()`! Instead, you derive from `std::streambuf``. The only reason to then derive from the stream classes is to easily construct a stream using a specific kind if stream buffer.

Answer (score 2):

There are three pimary reasons which lead to the creation of Iostreams I'm aware of:

1. Formatted I/O is not type-safe when using C's I/O facilities. Despite compilers possibly checking format strings against the actual use uses of `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` tend to be riddled with type errors. By using overload detecting the involved types these errors are prevented.
2. The C formatted I/O can't be extended to support user-defined types in a predictable an consistent way. C++ also addresses this problem by overloading operators.
3. C's I/O can't be extended by users to support additional sources and/or destinations. The C++ stream library defines an extensible interface (`std::streambuf`) supporting the creation of new kinds of streams.

C++ also provides support for per-stream localization wich in turn allows changing the format used for built-in numeric types, character classification, and translation between the internal and external encodings. Localization support was, however, added somewhat as an afterthought and isn't really nicely integrated.

tl;dr: C++ IOstreams are way more powerful than C's I/O support.

Answer (score 1):

Why does anyone ever make anything new? Why do new models of cars come out every year? We already have cars, right?

C++ streams were introduced because their authors thought they were better than C's I/O model.

Among other things, they have type safety, the lack of which is a big problem in C.

> I keep coming across the term "standard" IO. Is there something such as nonstandard IO too?

Sure — any library that does I/O that is not part of the C++ standard library.